# how to create trigger to split datetime into date

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Why does this trigger not work ? I try to create trigger which insert a single date from datetime.

Example like this :

When I insert datetime, trigger will insert date, month, year, dayname, age in other column.

The datetime, date month, year, dayname, age is in same table.

```
  ╔══════════════════════════════╦══════╦═══════╦══════╦═════════╦══════════╗
  ║           DateTime           ║ DATE ║ MONTH ║ YEAR ║ DAYNAME ║ Age      ║
  ╠══════════════════════════════╬══════╬═══════╬══════╬═════════╬══════════╣
  ║ April, 06 1982 00:00:00+0000 ║    4 ║     6 ║ 1982 ║ Friday  ║       31 ║
  ╚══════════════════════════════╩══════╩═══════╩══════╩═════════╩══════════╝

CREATE TRIGGER tgl
    ON penduduk
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    DECLARE
    @myDate CHAR(11)
    SELECT @myDate=tgl_lahir FROM inserted
    INSERT INTO penduduk(tgl) VALUES (datename(day,@myDate))
```

When I try the code above I got message

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 2, Procedure tgl, Line 8
>   There is already an object named 'tgl' in the database.

Should I create column date, month year, dayname and age before I create trigger ?

Comment: **If** it makes sense to decompose the date like this, it would seem more sensible to use [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) rather than using a trigger.

Comment: In the meantime, your trigger is broken anyway, since it assumes that there's exactly one row in `inserted`. This is not generally true. `inserted` can contain 0, 1, or multiple rows.

Comment: i just want to try. that. couldn't i ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: it would be **much easier** to just define **computed columns** for this and let SQL Server handle updating those as needed automatically:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.penduduk
   ADD DateYear AS YEAR(DateTimeColumn) PERSISTED,
       DateMonth AS MONTH(DateTimeColumn) PERSISTED,
       DateDay AS DAY(DateTimeColumn) PERSISTED
```

and so on.

Secondly, if you **insist** on using a trigger - then **YES** you **MUST** create the columns before hand! Otherwise, you'll attempt to create the same columns over and over again - hence the error. Also: what do you do when the `DateTimeColumn` is updated? You'll probably need a second trigger for that....

Also: you need to be aware that the trigger in SQL Server is run **once per statement** - and **NOT** once per row! Your `Inserted` pseudo table can contain **multiple rows**, so you need to code accordingly! Don't just select a value from the table - after all, you could have 100 rows in that table! Which row would you be selecting from??

Create the columns in your table **before** first run of your app:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.penduduk
   ADD DateDay INT, DateMonth INT, DateYear INT   etc.
```

Then create a trigger something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgl ON dbo.penduduk
FOR INSERT
AS
    UPDATE dbo.penduduk
    SET DateDay = DAY(i.DateTimeColumn),
        DateMonth = MONTH(i.DateTimeColumn),
        DateYear = YEAR(i.DateTimeColumn)
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.PrimaryKeyColumn = dbo.penduduk.PrimaryKeyColumn
```

Comment: thanks, finally it possible, i've try some way, but this one really works :)

Comment: I'm sure computed columns exist in the 2000 edition. If you want to highlight some reason why 2005 is required (e.g `PERSISTED`) please do so (even though I agree with the general ethos of not supporting ancient editions)